# What complimentary close to use in continuous formal email?

Tags: formality, email, letter-writing, valediction

I am a student in contact with a business owner, and I am having a hard time deciding on a complimentary close. Should I use it for every email I send him? I don't want to make it redundant since it is for formality's sake.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Vavein. You might want to visit English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is very helpful in answering basic questions.

Comment: Yes. Every time. Unless you are exchanging the mails in an interactive sense like you would in chat.

Comment: @Kris say for example sir, i have written down as my complimentary close for my first reply as "Sincerely Yours", does it mean that i would be using "sincerely yours" for the rest of my email messages with the business owner?

Comment: @Susan I am currently searching the pages for it maam, and so far i  have not found any relative questions which is the same to what i am looking for.

Comment: At ELL, you can post the same question, and someone will either help you with it, or point you to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formal emails/letters to a business owner/principal/someone of authority, you'd use "Yours sincerely" or "Yours faithfully", followed by your name on the next line.

"Sincerely" is used when you **don't know** the person's name. (ie. Dear Sir; Yours sincerely)

"Faithfully" is used when you **know** the person's name. (ie. Dear Mr Smith; Yours faithfully)

To make it easier to remember, you can just remember than the two "S" don't go together. (S from Sir and S from Sincerely)

If I were you, I'd just go with "Dear Mr xxx" and "Yours faithfully" every time I send an email. It won't be "redundant" as you call it. Many things in emails and everyday life are redundant. However, we still use it. Also, it's not redundant if it shows him how polite you are. It's better to be too formal than too casual. Being formal would also show him how serious and sincere you are in contacting him.

Hope this helps.